# Issue with converting char array to structure. char array variable of structure gets overflow

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, casting

I want to convert char array to structure but while printing I am getting following output

output: Test World (in line1)
st World(in line 2)

```
#pragma(1)
struct MyStruct
{
    char a[2];
    char b[5];
};

int main()
{
    char test[11] = "Test World";
    char *c = test;
    struct MyStruct *Test = (MyStruct*)(c);
    cout << Test->a << endl;
    cout << Test->b;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

I want the output according to the size of the structure variable.
My expected output: Te (in line 1)
                    st wo (in line 2)

Comment: You can't do it with `reinterpret_cast` without undefined behaviour. Don't do it.

Comment: You can't do it with C-style cast either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with your program.

Firstly, you indirect through a `MyStruct` pointer which doesn't point to a `MyStruct` (nor compatible) object. Therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Secondly, the string `Te` simply does not fit into `MyStruct::a` because there is not sufficient space. The string `Te` contains three characters, and `MyStruct::a` is only 2. Only the characters are `T` and `e` fit, but there is no room for the null terminator character, so it cannot be a null terminated string. The same problem is with your expectation of what fits in `MyStruct::b`.

Maybe it was your intention to not have a null terminated string, but then your problem is that you insert the non-null-terminated character array into the standard stream `std::cout`, which requires the argument to be a null terminated string. As a result of violating this requirement, the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

Here is one possible snippet that would have well defined behaviour and would have the desired output:

```
MyStruct Test;
std::memcpy(&Test, test, sizeof Test);
for(char c : Test.a)
   std::cout << c;
std::cout << '\n';
for(char c : Test.b)
   std::cout << c;
```

Answer (score 0):

C strins are zero terminated. So you need to add terminating zeroes to the fields of the struct. https://godbolt.org/z/kfsioP

```
struct MyStruct
{
    char a[2];
    char b[5];
};

int main()
{
    char test[11] = "Test World";
    char *c = test;
    struct MyStruct *Test = (MyStruct*)(c);
    Test -> a[sizeof(Test -> a) - 1] = 0;
    Test -> b[sizeof(Test -> b) - 1] = 0;
    std::cout << Test->a << std::endl;
    std::cout << Test->b;
    return 0;
}
```